# Selenium/PHPUnit: End a session when re-using browser sessions?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I'm runnig Selenium tests with PHPUnit.

I have some long test sequences split into several test files to make them easier to maintain.
For higher speed I would like to re-use the browser session for these cases.

I am able to reuse the sessions (PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase::shareSession(true)), but I cannot figure out how to end the session and open a new one before starting the next tests (which require a fresh browser session).

I have tried using the following line in the tearDown() method of the test to kill the current browser session

```
$this->stop();
```

this kills the browser, but generates an error: "Session xxxxxx does not exist or was ended"

=> Exactly, but how do I get Selenium to start a new session in this case?

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

When I create a few tests method in my test class (test file), **I don't use**

```
$this->stop();
```

in tearDown() method. 
I noticed that at the end of each test, the browser simply closes itself. I just set browser and browser URL in setUp() method and I open it in every test method by using

```
$this->open('/');
```

Have you tried in this simple way?

Comment: Thank you for your input - yes indeed, this works as you describe, but I want to keep the browser session open after a test and re-use it for the next one.

After a chain of tests I want to kill the browser session and start a new one.

In short: I want the browser sessions to be re-used by default, but for some tests I would like to be able to close the session and open a new one.

Comment: OK, I get it. Maybe this could help: http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_frm/thread/418087a0f93ece04/bc325d34b998241c?lnk=gst&q=Reusing+same+browser+#bc325d34b998241c

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the

> -browserSessionReuse

parameter when launching an Selenium RC node.

Comment: Hello Jochen, thanks for your answer. The way I understand it, `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase::shareSession(TRUE)` does exactly the same. My problem is how to end a browser session and start a new one when using this option